# I can fetch all data but cant pass to model

Tags: flutter, http, dio

Im fetching some data. In my model, i have to fromjson func.

```
  List<Results>? results;
  Movie({this.page, this.results});
  Movie.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    page = json['page'];
    results = <Results>[];
    json['results'].forEach((v) {
      results!.add(Results.fromJson(v));
    });
  }
}

class Results {
  bool? adult;
  String? backdropPath;
  ...

  Results(
      {this.adult,
      this.backdropPath,
      ...});

  Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    adult = json['adult'];
    backdropPath = json['backdrop_path'];
...
  }
}
```

this is my model folder. I can print my data in Results.fromJson func. But in the Movie.fromJson's forEach, i cant get any data.

```
late Future<Movie> movieData;

  @override
  Future<void> init() async {
    movieData = GetMovies().getMovies();

}
```

This is my how to call my model an the my service's return code is that;

```
 return Movie.fromJson(response.data);
```

Comment: add the data you use to parse and also what's the error